# New/Edit form (InfoPath) accesses more than one list

Tags: 2013, infopath

Is it possible to access more than one SP list in a single InfoPath form?

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is very much possible, in fact that is what Infopath form is meant for. You have to create multiple datasources and connect to list to access its object.

Providing reference links.

https://support.office.com/en-us/article/submit-form-data-to-several-locations-f4fb6fdf-b472-44ea-992c-1acbec3c9763

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/cee7a64a-7290-47a2-bda6-118ca7a9ed19/how-to-submit-infopath-form-data-to-multiple-sharepoint-lists-at-one-time?forum=sharepointcustomizationlegacy